# JS is or is not if else

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, if-statement, sequelize.js

How could I simplify this action below.
I realize this is ridiculous.

But everything I'm trying to do, either one works and one doesn't and vice versa.

I need to send data if this field is not empty. if it is empty, then don't send it: `admin|power`

it's either null or not

```
const mreq = await Model.findOne({
  where: {
    id: req.params.id,
    old: req.params.times
  }
})
if (!mreq) {
  return
} else if (mreq.admin == null) {
  return
} else if (mreq.admin) {
  res.json(mreq.admin)
} else if (mreq.power == null) {
  return
} else if (mreq.power) {
  res.json(mreq.power)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need all the branches that don't return anything - just test for the two values to be `.json`d in two `if`s. Use optional chaining to keep things concise.

```
const mreq = await Model.findOne({ where: { id: req.params.id, old: req.params.times } })
if (mreq?.admin) {
    res.json(mreq.admin)
} else if (mreq?.power) {
    res.json(mreq.power)
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed. That's what I was stupid about. Thank you very much. Such a silly question I had, you helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that perhaps the property "admin" can be boolean (I don't konw)
You can do something like this:

```
if(mreq && mreq.admin !== null) { 
res.json(mreq.admin);
return;
} 

if (mreq.power) {  res.json(mreq.power) }
```

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. Thanks for the observation mate.